# NullPointerException from null array cells

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

Using Java and no IDE, but rather the command line, I'm supposed to write a basic-ish phone book program focusing around arrays in which the user has three options: search for a name in an array and print the name and phone number if the name is found, add a new name and phone number to the array based on user input, and delete a name and number from the array based on user input. The add function works exactly how it should, but the search and delete functions do not function properly. My code compiles and runs, but I get a NullPointerException runtime error whenever I try to search for or delete a name that doesn't exist in the array.

These are the specific instructions for the 'delete entry' part of the program:

*"To delete a name and number from such an array, first find the name's cell. If the name to delete is not in the array, report an error. Now copy the reference in the last non-null cell to the deleted name's cell. Set the last non-null cell to to null. Now the deleted PhoneEntry is garbage, and all the array still has all the nulls at the end."*

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;

class PhoneEntry
{
    String name;    // name of a person
    String phone;   // their phone number

    PhoneEntry( String n, String p )
    {
        name = n; phone = p;
    }
}

class PhoneBook
{
    PhoneEntry[] phoneBook;

    PhoneBook()    // constructor
    {
        phoneBook = new PhoneEntry[ 10 ] ;

        phoneBook[0] = new PhoneEntry( "James Barclay", "(418) 665-1223" );
        phoneBook[1] = new PhoneEntry( "Grace Dunbar",  "(860) 399-3044" );
        phoneBook[2] = new PhoneEntry( "Paul Kratides", "(815) 439-9271" );
        phoneBook[3] = new PhoneEntry( "Violet Smith",  "(312) 223-1937" );
        phoneBook[4] = new PhoneEntry( "John Wood",     "(913) 883-2874" );
        phoneBook[5] = new PhoneEntry( null, null );
        phoneBook[6] = new PhoneEntry( null, null );
        phoneBook[7] = new PhoneEntry( null, null );
        phoneBook[8] = new PhoneEntry( null, null );
        phoneBook[9] = new PhoneEntry( null, null );
    }

    PhoneEntry search( String targetName )
    {
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < phoneBook.length ; i++ )
        {
            System.out.println(i);  // debug
            if ( phoneBook[i] != null && phoneBook[i].name.equals( targetName ) )
            {
                return phoneBook[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    PhoneEntry addEntry( String addName, String addNumber )
    {
        boolean found = false;
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < phoneBook.length ; i++ )
        {
            System.out.println(i);  // debug
            if ( phoneBook[i].name == null )
            {
                phoneBook[i] = new PhoneEntry( addName, addNumber );
                found = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
        if ( !found )
        {
            System.out.println("Phone book is full! Delete an entry first!");
        }
        return null;
    }

    PhoneEntry deleteEntry( String deleteName )
    {
        boolean found = false;
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < phoneBook.length ; i++ )
        {
            System.out.println(i);  // debug
            if ( phoneBook[i] != null && phoneBook[i].name.equals( deleteName ) )
            {
                System.out.println( phoneBook[i].name + " found");  // debug
                phoneBook[i] = new PhoneEntry( null, null );
                found = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
        if ( !found )
        {
            System.out.println( "Entry not found." );
        }
        return null;
    }
}

class PhoneBookComplete
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        PhoneBook pb = new PhoneBook();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );
        String tempName, tempNumber, tempDelName;

            // INITIAL WELCOME MESSAGE START

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("**********************");
        System.out.println("***** PHONE BOOK *****");
        System.out.println("**********************");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(" 1  Search for an entry");
        System.out.println(" 2  Add a new entry");
        System.out.println(" 3  Delete an entry");
        System.out.println(" 4  Quit program");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Enter a command: ");

        String userInput = scan.nextLine();
        PhoneEntry entry;
        System.out.println();

            // INITIAL WELCOME MESSAGE END

        while ( userInput != "quit" )
        {
            if ( userInput.equals("1") )        //  NAME SEARCH
            {
                    System.out.println("    NAME SEARCH START");
                System.out.println("**********************");
                System.out.println("***** NAME SEARCH ****");
                System.out.println("**********************");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print("Enter a name: ");
                userInput = scan.nextLine();
                entry = pb.search( userInput );

                if ( entry != null )
                {
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println( "  " + entry.name + ": " + entry.phone );
                    System.out.println();
                }
                else if ( userInput.equals("quit") )
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Name not found.");
                    System.out.println();
                }
                    System.out.println("    NAME SEARCH END");
                    System.out.println();
            }
            else if ( userInput.equals("2") )   //  ADD ENTRY
            {
                    System.out.println("    ADD ENTRY START");

                System.out.println("**********************");
                System.out.println("***** ADD ENTRY ******");
                System.out.println("**********************");
                System.out.println();

                System.out.print("Enter full name: ");
                tempName = scan.nextLine();

                    if ( userInput.equals("quit") )
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                System.out.print("Enter phone number: ");
                tempNumber = scan.nextLine();

                    if ( userInput.equals("quit") )
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                entry = pb.addEntry( tempName, tempNumber );

                System.out.println();
                System.out.println( "Entry for " + tempName + " successfully added." );
                //System.out.println("Phone book is full! Delete an entry first!");

                    System.out.println("    ADD ENTRY END");
                    System.out.println();
            }
            else if ( userInput.equals("3") )   //  DELETE ENTRY
            {
                    System.out.println("    DELETE ENTRY START");

                System.out.println("**********************");
                System.out.println("**** DELETE ENTRY ****");
                System.out.println("**********************");
                System.out.println();

                System.out.print("Enter full name: ");
                tempDelName = scan.nextLine();
                entry = pb.deleteEntry( tempDelName );

                if ( entry == null )
                {
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println( "Entry for " + tempDelName + " successfully deleted." );
                    System.out.println();
                }
                else if ( userInput.equals("quit") )
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println();
                }

                    System.out.println("    DELETE ENTRY END");
                    System.out.println();
            }
            else if ( userInput.equals("4") )   //  QUIT PROGRAM
            {
                    System.out.println();
                break;
            }

            //System.out.println("Select a command:");
            System.out.println("**********************");
            System.out.println("**********************");
            System.out.println("**********************");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(" 1  Search for an entry");
            System.out.println(" 2  Add a new entry");
            System.out.println(" 3  Delete an entry");
            System.out.println(" 4  Quit program");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Enter a command: ");
            userInput = scan.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println("Goodbye.");
    }
}
```

Here is the error that I get when I try to search for a nonexistent name:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at PhoneBook.search(PhoneBookComplete.java:39)
        at PhoneBookComplete.main(PhoneBookComplete.java:128)
```

And here is the error that I get when I try to delete a nonexistent name:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at PhoneBook.deleteEntry(PhoneBookComplete.java:73)
        at PhoneBookComplete.main(PhoneBookComplete.java:193)
```

I know this has something to do with my use of null, but what the heck else would I use instead of null? Also, I'm *supposed* to use null anyways.

So I guess my question is: What should be modified in my code so that when a user attempts to delete or search for a nonexistent name, an error message is printed *without* crashing the program?

When answering, please keep in mind that I'm very new to Java, and arrays, methods and whatnot are still quite confusing to me. If anymore information, etc. is needed, please ask and thou shall receive. With that said, any help and explanations of anything whatsoever is appreciated and more than welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that name isn't `null` as well, this

```
if (phoneBook[i] != null && phoneBook[i].name.equals(targetName))
```

should be something like

```
if (phoneBook[i] != null && targetName.equals(phoneBook[i].name))
```

and in `deleteEntry` like

```
if (phoneBook[i] != null && deleteName.equals(phoneBook[i].name))
```

because when the `phoneBook[i].name` is `null` it causes `NullPointerException` to call `.equals()` on it. You could also add a `null` test on `.name` but then you need another `&&` like

```
if (phoneBook[i] != null && phoneBook[i].name != null &&
    phoneBook[i].name.equals(targetName))
```

Comment: Are you a wizard? Oh my goodness, yes! It works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found your problem.

```
if ( phoneBook[i] != null && phoneBook[i].name.equals( deleteName ) )
```

This checks whether the entry is null, but doesn't check the actual name to see if it's null.

It should be

```
if ( phoneBook[i].name != null && phoneBook[i].name.equals( deleteName ) )
```

The code would work if instead of

```
phoneBook[5] = new PhoneEntry( null, null );
```

You used

```
phoneBook[5] = null;
```